# Translation not working for custom user roles

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am using the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module. I created 2 custom roles: *venue user* and *customer user*. When I log in as administrator user, the translation is working fine; when we log in either as *venue user* or *customer user*, the translation does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant translation related permissions for the two roles you have created. For changing the permissions, go to `/admin/people/permissions`, then set the translation related permissions for the two roles. 
If you want the two roles to translate content, then you need to grant **Translate content** permission for the roles.

Comment: I have already given the permission but its work only for admin user not anyone login . Or without login its working fine .